# Increase Open Query performance

Tags: sql-server

I have a small problem with this query. It returns me around 13k rows and takes around 12seconds or more.

```
SELECT 
    hla.Id,
    hc.Nome AS Colaborador,
    hla.UAP,
    hra.Referencia, 
    hra.QtdAbastecimento, 
    hra.QtdPecasPorCaixa, 
    hra.QtdCaixas,
    A.Etiqueta, 
    A.Localizacao
FROM 
    hListasAbastecimento hla
INNER JOIN hColaboradores hc
ON hc.Id = hla.ColaboradorId
INNER JOIN 
    hReferenciasAbastecimento hra
ON hla.Id = hra.ListaAbastecimentoId
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        FET001.ET0102 AS Referencia,
        FET001.ET0101 AS Etiqueta, 
        FET001.ET0109 AS Localizacao
    FROM 
        AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
    WHERE FET001.ET0104 = ''POE'' 
    AND FET001.ET0105 = ''DIS''
    ORDER BY FET001.ET0101 ASC ') A
ON A.Referencia = hra.Referencia 
WHERE hla.Id = @Id
```

I'm not sure what can i do to increase the performance of this. I am already using the only primary key to link both tables. I also have no control over the linked server so i cannot create new indexes

**UPDATE**

I found out through a co-worker that there was a table on linked server that could help me get results by "UAP" which takes only 4 seconds just to get around 1700 rows which is what i needed

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GenerateListaAbastecimento
    @Id INT,
    @UAP NVARCHAR(20)
    AS
BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #tempTable
        (
            Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
            Referencia NVARCHAR(15),
            Etiqueta INT,
            Localizacao NVARCHAR(20)

            UNIQUE(Id, Etiqueta)
        )

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @SQL ='INSERT INTO #tempTable    
        SELECT 
            Id, 
            Referencia, 
            Etiqueta, 
            Localizacao 
        FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        ''SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FET001.ET0101 ASC) AS Id,
            A.RH6001 as Referencia, 
            FET001.ET0101 AS Etiqueta, 
            FET001.ET0109 AS Localizacao
        FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
        LEFT JOIN AUTO.D805DATPOR.FET001 FET001
        ON FET001.ET0102 = A.RH6001
        AND FET001.ET0104 = ''''POE'''' 
        AND FET001.ET0105 = ''''DIS'''' 
        AND A.RH6002 = N'''  + QUOTENAME(@UAP,N'''') +  N''' '')'   

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

    SELECT 
        hla.Id,
        hc.Nome AS Colaborador,
        hla.UAP,
        hra.Referencia, 
        hra.QtdAbastecimento, 
        hra.QtdPecasPorCaixa, 
        hra.QtdCaixas,
        A.Etiqueta, 
        A.Localizacao
    FROM 
        hListasAbastecimento hla
    INNER JOIN hColaboradores hc
    ON hc.Id = hla.ColaboradorId
    INNER JOIN 
        hReferenciasAbastecimento hra
    ON hla.Id = hra.ListaAbastecimentoId
    LEFT JOIN #tempTable A
    ON A.Referencia = hra.Referencia 
    WHERE hla.Id = @Id
    ORDER BY A.Etiqueta ASC

    DROP TABLE #tempTable

END
```

Comment: For sure you can resign from ORDER BY.

Comment: ah a small detail i missed. this actually made it faster around 2-3 seconds, i redid order by to do on local server instead remote one

Comment: It is difficult to help when you only show **PART** of a query and provide no detail about the tables involved. You went from a partial query (no definition of local variable used) to a stored procedure with 2 arguments. Properly parameterizing your dynamic sql would be an best practice. You don't use the row_number value so removing it would also help.